# Ограничение на создание вкладок QTabWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Как создать ограничение на кол-во создаваемых вкладок в `QTabWidget` допустим у меня будет кнопка на создание новой вкладки но надо сделать так чтобы она не создавала больше 3 вкладок

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
def center():
    qr = root.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    root.move(qr.topLeft())
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root= QWidget()
hbox = QHBoxLayout(root)
topleft = QFrame(root)
topleft.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
topleft.resize(10,0)
topright = QFrame(root)
topright.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
splitter1.addWidget(topleft)
splitter1.addWidget(topright)
hbox.addWidget(splitter1)
hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()
tab = QTabWidget()
First_frame_of_the_Right_frame = QFrame()
tab.addTab(First_frame_of_the_Right_frame, "Основа")  # вкладки
Second_frame_of_the_Right_frame = QFrame()
tab.addTab(Second_frame_of_the_Right_frame, "Дополнительно")
hbox1.addWidget(tab)
topright.setLayout(hbox1)
root.setLayout(hbox)
root.setFixedSize(1366,720)
center()
root.setWindowTitle('QSplitter')
menubar = QMenuBar()
closefile = QAction( 'Закрыть', root)
closefile.triggered.connect(lambda : Second_frame_of_the_Right_frame.close())
fileMenu_file = menubar.addMenu('File')
fileMenu_file.addAction(closefile)
hbox.setMenuBar(menubar)
root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
tab.tabCloseRequested.connect(closeTab)
```

Comment: Лучше приводите в вопрос минимальный пример, чтобы можно было запустить, подправить где неправильно и выдать как ответ, а не воссоздавать пример с нуля :)

Comment: @gil9red сейчас исправлю извиняюсь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ – контроль количества вкладок.

В текущем виде примере в методе создания проверяется текущее количество вкладок и при выходе за лимиты применяются действия, это может быть игнорирование, либо можно показать сообщение `QMessageBox.information(self, 'Info', 'Max tab!')`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

        tool_bar = self.addToolBar('General')
        action = tool_bar.addAction('Add tab')
        action.triggered.connect(self.add_tab)

    def add_tab(self):
        if self.tab_widget.count() >= 3:
            return

        tab = QTextEdit()
        self.tab_widget.addTab(tab, str(self.tab_widget.count() + 1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

Но правильный пример – полный контроль на вкладками и вместо тихого игнорирования действий пользователя показывать что действие запрещено.

Добавил обработку закрытия вкладки и две кнопки: создания вкладки и удаление текущей.

Если действие нельзя выполнить, например добавить или удалить вкладку, тогда ее кнопка будет неактивной:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()
        self.tab_widget.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.tab_widget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self._on_close_tab)

        tool_bar = self.addToolBar('General')
        self.action_add_tab = tool_bar.addAction('Add tab')
        self.action_add_tab.triggered.connect(self.add_tab)

        self.action_remove_tab = tool_bar.addAction('Remove tab')
        self.action_remove_tab.triggered.connect(self.remove_tab)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)

        self.update_states()

    def update_states(self):
        self.action_add_tab.setEnabled(self.tab_widget.count() < 3)
        self.action_remove_tab.setEnabled(self.tab_widget.count() > 0)

    def add_tab(self):
        tab = QTextEdit()
        self.tab_widget.addTab(tab, str(self.tab_widget.count() + 1))

        self.update_states()

    def remove_tab(self):
        index = self.tab_widget.currentIndex()
        self._on_close_tab(index)

    def _on_close_tab(self, index):
        if index == -1:
            return

        self.tab_widget.removeTab(index)

        self.update_states()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: или они все будут как General?

Comment: Кто? Что как General?

Comment: Ну т.е. в дальнейшем мне нужно будет допустим на форму 2 добавить кнопки ну или радиокнопки как их в данном случае добавить?

Comment: По моему, этот вопрос не относится к текущей теме. `General` это просто название ToolBar на форме, которое будет видно при клике правой кнопкой и в качестве action'а в Menu. Кнопки добавите на какой виджет хотите, можете на текущий tool_bar добавить, только если к нему нужно обращение из другого метода MainWindow или напрямую другим объектом, сделайте его полем объекта через `self.tool_bar`